# How can I fire a custom Angular filter from ng-change from the html?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

Lets say I have two dropdowns that are populated with numbers using a min value and a max value for example 0 and 9.

I populate them using a filter

```
export class NumberRangeFilter {

    public static Factory() {
        return function(input: number[], min: number, max: number) {
            for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                input.push(i);
            }
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

which is invoked in the html

```
ng-repeat="n for n in [] | numberrange:vm.minAllowedAdults:vm.maxAllowedAdults"
```

This works great. However the numbers in both combos can only ever add up to a max value for example 9. If 5 is selected in combo 1 then combo 2 should update to only show options 0 - 4.

Can this be achieved by invoking the filter that already exists from the html using an ng-change whilst keeping as much of the logic out of the controller as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the max depending on each other.

```
var total = 9;
dropDown1Max = total - dropDown2Value;
dropDown2Max = total - dropDown1Value;
```

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just use the limitTo filter provided by angular `[] | limitTo:numLimit`. Where numLimit points to the value chosen in the first dropdown.